# ChaiScript: Exposing data member variables of a class

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, chaiscript

I'm trying to expose `Ogre::Vector2` class to ChaiScript. I want to expose the `x` and `y` of the class and [as-per this post on their forum](http://chaiscript.com/node/128), it seems like you just need to add it like any other function. But that doesn't work for me and it gives me the following error message:

> "Error with function dispatch for function 'x'" With parameters:
>   (const class Ogre::Vector2).()

**NOTE**: I've tried accessing them as `v.x` and `v.x()` inside of the script.

My definition of the module looks like this:

```
using namespace chaiscript;
ModulePtr module(new Module());
module->add(user_type<Ogre::Vector2>(), "Ogre::Vector2");
module->add(constructor<Ogre::Vector2()>(), "Ogre::Vector2");
module->add(constructor<Ogre::Vector2(float, float)>(), "Ogre::Vector2");
module->add(constructor<Ogre::Vector2(float)>(), "Ogre::Vector2");
module->add(constructor<Ogre::Vector2(const Ogre::Vector2&)>(), "Ogre::Vector2");
module->add(fun(&Ogre::Vector2::x), "x");
module->add(fun(&Ogre::Vector2::y), "y");
module->add(fun<Ogre::Vector2& (Ogre::Vector2::*)(const Ogre::Vector2&)>(&Ogre::Vector2::operator =), "=");
module->add(fun<Ogre::Vector2 (Ogre::Vector2::*)(const Ogre::Vector2&) const>(&Ogre::Vector2::operator+), "+");
module->add(fun<Ogre::Vector2 (Ogre::Vector2::*)(const Ogre::Vector2&) const>(&Ogre::Vector2::operator-), "-");
module->add(fun<Ogre::Vector2 (Ogre::Vector2::*)(const Ogre::Vector2&) const>(&Ogre::Vector2::operator*), "*");
module->add(fun<Ogre::Vector2 (Ogre::Vector2::*)(const float) const>(&Ogre::Vector2::operator*), "*");
module->add(fun<Ogre::Vector2 (Ogre::Vector2::*)(const Ogre::Vector2&) const>(&Ogre::Vector2::operator/), "/");
module->add(fun<Ogre::Vector2 (Ogre::Vector2::*)(const float) const>(&Ogre::Vector2::operator/), "/");
```

I had initially tried defining this class via their [class helper macro](http://www.chaiscript.com/doxygen/index.html#helpermacro) and went on to manually define this module by-hand having encountered this error. Since their forum has disabled new-topic creations and new posts (DARN you, spammers!), I'm posting this question here. Any help to resolve this issue would be much appreciated.

**NOTE2**: I'm using ChaiScript-4.2.0

Comment: Sorry, I've not paid as close attention to StackOverflow as I should have... it looks like there's a problem with accessing member variable on a const object, which I don't have a unit test for yet. I'll look into it and get back ASAP.

Comment: I added explicit tests for this case and don't see any issue https://github.com/ChaiScript/ChaiScript/commit/d44de49fb1e34e146442a527193b656ee059aafb I need more details about your calling code.

Comment: @lefticus: I finally figured out what the issue was and it's quite stupid. I had the default constructor (by the virtue of copy-pasting) which was from a different structure, which was `Ogre::Vector3`. Sorry about the confusion. I feel really stupid!